# What's the most optimal way to find 4 consecutive equal chars in a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, optimization, logic

The challenge is to find 4 consecutive equal characters in horizontal, vertical or diagonal direction with the most optimal algorithm possible.

For example, if we have this matrix:

[

['L','T','G','C',**'T','A'**],

['X','A','G',**'T',**'G',**'A'**],

['T','R',**'T',**'K','G',**'A'**],

['A',**'T',**'A','M','G',**'A'**],

[**'C','C','C','C'**,'T','G'],

['V','C','D','C','T','W']

]

the algorithm should find `AAAA` (vertical), `CCCC` (horizontal) and `TTTT` (inverted diagonal).

How would you do it? Any programming language can be used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that any naive algorithm is going to take `O(M)` time to do the task (`M` the number of elements in the array), and that you can't possibly make any better since you have to visit at least once all the cells of your array. So if the task is not about implementation speed but about `O` notation, I'd say a simple and naive approach would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Boogle board problem modified with repeated strings.

I believe that you can solve in `O(N*M)` time where `N`: Number of columns and `M`: Number of rows.

The approach that you can do is a BFS with memory in already matched strings and mark as visited.

In this link you can see a implementation with dictionaries. You'll need to get a modification to get repeated strings `o` times: https://gist.github.com/davidreynolds/2865498